# How can I update my circular progress according to my data in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api

I am building a MERN application, and I want to use a circular progress in the dashboad of the app. What a want to is that when I fetched data fron API end point, I want the circular progress update the circular indication according to the data numbers fetched. I have try to implement that, there is piece of puzzle I am missing there so the circular indicator can move according to the pourcentage's number. The only thing is not working is the circulor that indicate the pourcentage of number. Can someone give some advice how I can solve it? thanks.
Here below is what I am trying to do:

[image]

**ProgressCircular.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useColorIndication } from "./useColorIndication";
import { ProgressArc } from "./ProgressArc";
import axios from "axios";

export function ProgressCircleWrapper() {
  const svgWidth = 150;
  const arcWidth = 12;
  const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState([]);
  const [progressPercentage, setProgressPercentage] = useState(0);
  const colorIndicator = useColorIndication(progressPercentage);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/dashboard")
      .then((res) => {
        setDashboard(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  function valueText(value) {
    return `${value}°C`;
  }

  function setProgressValue(event, value) {
    setProgressPercentage(value);
  }

  return (
    <Box padding="3rem" justifyContent="center">
      {dashboard &&
        dashboard.map((item, index) => (
          <Box key={index} width="50%">
            <ProgressArc
              svgWidth={svgWidth}
              arcWidth={arcWidth}
              dashboard={item.wasteFromProduction}
              progressPercentage={progressPercentage}
              colorIndicator={colorIndicator}
              defaultValue={0}
              getAriaValueText={valueText}
              aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
              step={1}
              marks
              min={0}
              max={100}
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              onChange={(event, value) => {
                setProgressValue(event, value);
              }}
            />
            <ProgressArc
              svgWidth={svgWidth}
              arcWidth={arcWidth}
              dashboard={item.wrappingPackaging}
              progressPercentage={progressPercentage}
              colorIndicator={colorIndicator}
              defaultValue={0}
              getAriaValueText={valueText}
              aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
              step={1}
              marks
              min={0}
              max={100}
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              onChange={(event, value) => {
                setProgressValue(event, value);
              }}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**ProgressArc.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

export function ProgressArc({
  svgWidth,
  arcWidth,
  dashboard,
  progressPercentage,
  colorIndicator,
}) {
  const svgHeight = svgWidth;
  const arcOuterRadius = svgWidth / 12;
  const arcInnerRadius = svgWidth / 7 - arcWidth;
  const arcGenerator = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(arcInnerRadius)
    .outerRadius(arcOuterRadius)
    .startAngle(0)
    .cornerRadius(5);
  const progressArc = (value) =>
    arcGenerator({
      endAngle: 2 * Math.PI * value,
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <svg height={svgHeight} width={svgWidth}>
        <g transform={`translate(${svgWidth / 2}, ${svgHeight / 2})`}>
          <path d={progressArc(1)} opacity="0.2" fill="gray" />
        </g>
        <g transform={`translate(${svgWidth / 2}, ${svgHeight / 2})`}>
          <path
            d={progressArc(progressPercentage / 100)}
            fill={colorIndicator}
          />
          <text x="20" y="5">
            {`${dashboard}`}
          </text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useColorIndicator.js:**

```
 import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useColorIndication(progressPercentage: number) {
  const [colorIndicator, setColor] = useState("red");
  useEffect(() => {
    progressPercentage >= 50 ? setColor("green") : setColor("red");
  }, [progressPercentage]);
  return colorIndicator;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the get request progress?

Comment: I am trying to make the circular progress show the pourcentage according to the number of data.

Comment: From where you are getting the number of data?

Comment: from my mongodb in the backend

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem:

You are not updating the progressPercentage value, it is always 0%

#### Solution:

If you are trying to set the `progress` of a GET request you can use `onDownloadProgress`:

```
axios
  .get("http://localhost:3001/dashboard", {
    onDownloadProgress: progressEvent => {
      console.log(progressEvent)
      //--> set the progress value here
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    setDashboard(res.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If you are trying to get the percent value from the dashboard item property:

```
<ProgressArc
   svgWidth={svgWidth}
   arcWidth={arcWidth}
   dashboard={item.wasteFromProduction}
   progressPercentage={item.wasteFromProduction.replace(/[^\d]/g, "")}
   colorIndicator={colorIndicator}
   defaultValue={0}
   getAriaValueText={valueText}
   //...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices @lissettdm, can you explain more?

Comment: I need to understand what are you trying to accomplish. This progress if for every item?

Comment: You do want some animation or just set the item percent according to the total?

Comment: I need to make the circular bar move according to the pourcentage's number, for exemple  for those two circulars have the pourcentage of 34% and 50%, what I am expecting is that the circular has also to indicate those two numbers in the circle. I don't if I explain it well

Comment: Do you take this percentage from this props item.wasteFromProduction and item.wrappingPackaging?

Comment: I just want the circular progress move according to the pourcentage of the number, as you can see there is only pourcentage number but there nothing in indicate in the circle.

Comment: these pourcentage are coming from api backend

Comment: Are this values in dashboard?, for example item.wasteFromProduction is equal 50%, you take the 50 from here or from other property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230706/discussion-between-saygas-and-lissettdm).

Answer (score 0):

The data is fetched one time, and after fetching you display the circular program from your data. So don't expect the circular will animate, it will stay with fetched data.

Comment: thanks fir your input @Soufiane Boutahlit, what I am to do is that when the data is fetched the circilar should indicate the pourcentage of data. As you can see in the screen shoot, there is nothing on both circular progres. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to change this   d={progressArc(progressPercentage / 100)} to  d={progressArc(dashboard/ 100)} and make sure that the value of dashboard is a number.